# How Spring Data Neo4j abstraction handles creation & update (repository.save)

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

For the purposes of testing, I created a simple domain in the form of a tree of companies and their orders, so:

- company delivers orders
- company has only one company above
- company can have multiple collectors below

And this is how I represented it:

```
@Node
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(UUIDStringGenerator.class)
    private String id;

    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = "COLLECTS_FROM", direction = INCOMING)
    private Company parent;

    @Relationship(type = "COLLECTS_FROM")
    private Set<Company> children;

    @Relationship(type = "DELIVERS")
    private Set<Order> orders;

    //all args constructor with (thid.id = null)
    //getters and setters (omitted for brevity)
}   

@Node
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(UUIDStringGenerator.class)
    private String id;
    private final String partNumber;
    private final Integer quantityOrdered;
    private final Integer quantityReceived;
    
    //all args constructor with (thid.id = null)
    //getters and setters (omitted for brevity)
```

Of course, I have two very simple repositories:

```
@Repository
public interface CompanyRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Company, String> {
}
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Order, String> {
}
```

I created few integration tests:

```
    @Test
    void shouldCreateCompanyWithRelations() {
        Company parent = companyRepository.save(new Company("parent", null, null, null));
        Company firstChild = companyRepository.save(new Company("Child1", null, null, null));
        Company secondChild = companyRepository.save(new Company("Child2", null, null, null));
        Order firstOrder = orderRepository.save(new Order("part1", 10, 10));
        Order secondOrder = orderRepository.save(new Order("part2", 20, 20));
        Company testCompany = companyRepository.save(new Company("TestCompany", parent, Set.of(firstChild, secondChild), Set.of(firstOrder, secondOrder)));

        var result = companyRepository.findById(testCompany.getId());

        assertThat(result)
                .hasValueSatisfying(company -> {
                    assertThat(company.getId()).isNotNull();
                    assertThat(company.getName()).isEqualTo("TestCompany");
                    assertThat(company.getParent()).isNotNull(); //this assertion fails, returns null
                    assertThat(company.getChildren()).hasSize(2); //this assertion fails, returns 0
                    assertThat(company.getOrders()).hasSize(2);
                });
    }
```

- Expectation: all relations will be created.
- Reality: test fails due to missing relation to `parent` & `children` (same node), relation to orders exist (different node)

```
    @Test
    void createWithSingleSave() {
        Company parent = new Company("parent", null, null, null);
        Company firstChild = new Company("Child1", null, null, null);
        Company secondChild = new Company("Child2", null, null, null);
        Order firstOrder = new Order("part1", 10, 10);
        Order secondOrder = new Order("part2", 20, 20);
        Company testCompany = companyRepository.save(new Company("TestCompany", parent, Set.of(firstChild, secondChild), Set.of(firstOrder, secondOrder)));

        var result = companyRepository.findById(testCompany.getId());
```

- Expectation: cascade creation of all companies & orders
- Reality: `org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Error mapping Record<{__sn__: node<0>, __sr__: [relationship<0>, relationship<1>, relationship<2>, relationship<3>, relationship<4>], __srn__: [node<0>, node<1>, node<2>, node<3>, node<4>, node<5>]}>`

I have the assumption, that maybe it's not the `repo.save` issue, but `repo.findById()` issue, that' why I created the third test:

```
    @Test
    void basicPropertyUpdate() {
        //not sure if this initializatio work, because of the issue mentioned on test 1 & 2
        Company parent = companyRepository.save(new Company("parent", null, null, null));
        Company firstChild = companyRepository.save(new Company("Child1", null, null, null));
        Company secondChild = companyRepository.save(new Company("Child2", null, null, null));
        Order firstOrder = orderRepository.save(new Order("part1", 10, 10));
        Order secondOrder = orderRepository.save(new Order("part2", 20, 20));
        Company testCompany = companyRepository.save(new Company("TestCompany", parent, Set.of(firstChild, secondChild), Set.of(firstOrder, secondOrder)));

        var companyToUpdate = companyRepository.findById(testCompany.getId()).orElseThrow();
        companyToUpdate.setName("NewName");
        var updatedCompany = companyRepository.save(companyToUpdate);
```

- Expectation: will save only basic property
- Concern: if parent & children aren't nulls, and that's the findById issue while performing basic property update also the relation to parent & child will be overridden and will remove them.

I didn't write the fourth test, but it is related to how we should update relations e.g. by adding or removing the `child` set, relations of relations are safe or still can be overridden because relation nodes of relation nodes can be also nulls?

I have read all [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/6.1.5/reference/html/), but it didn't give me a clear answer (I will say more, it caused more misunderstanding). I used `Spring Boot 2.5.5` with `spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j` (Spring data neo4j 6.1.5)

I've given quite a bit of an introduction, but the question(s) seems relatively simple.

1. Why am I not able to create the above-mentioned structure (with the `repository.save`)? Or why is findById unable to recreate it?
2. How to correctly update basic property & relation of the existing nodes (with the `repository.save`) without fear that something will be accidentally deleted?